# Setting up payment method with get

Tags: php

Please help me guys setting up this payment check :) <3

This is the documentation i have :

```
Step 3 - Check payment
In this step we will check if the payment was really done.


URL: https://sandbox.paymee.tn/api/v1/payments/{token}/check
Request method: GET
Header
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Token api_key 
Input
token: The token received in Step 1
Output
If the buyer uses the wallet to pay, the buyer_id will be filled. Otherwise buyer_id is 0.

{
    "status": true,
    "message": "Success",
    "code": 50,
    "data": {
        "payment_status": true,
        "token": "5d41404b2a76b9719c592e6f84b68d92",
        "amount": 3.0,
        "transaction_id": 126627,
        "buyer_id": 10253
    }
}
```

This is the code they gave me to use :

```
$headers = array("Authorization: Token 12345678900987654321234567890");
$curl_handle=curl_init('https://sandbox.paymee.tn/api/v1/payments/9D320F732CE972A47E8C73E0A4D23BB0947/check');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$query = json_decode(curl_exec($curl_handle),true);
curl_close($curl_handle);
if ($query['data']['payment_status']==true) {
  // Payment successful
}
else {
  // Payment failed
}
```

The problem is that i'm not receiving anything when i use :

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($query); echo '</pre>';
```

Please help me i needed to finish this very quickly <3

Comment: I'd suggest `var_dump($query);` or the response from `curl_exec`. You'll see it's returning `{"detail":"Invalid token."}`

Comment: Separate your `curl_exec` from `json_decode` to make debugging easier. `$response = curl_exec($curl_handle);
var_dump($response);
$query = json_decode($response,true);
var_dump($query);` If the curl request returns anything but valid JSON, `json_decode` will return `NULL`, which will show as empty string with `print_r`.